# how to set the sessionID in the request header using android 2.2

Tags: android, http, http-headers

I am developing an application using android 2.2. I don't know how to manage the opened session between the server and the mobile app. I have a mobile app with login screen when the user enter his user name and password I send it to the server (php page) using the following code:

```
    httpMethod = new HttpPost(Constants.IOGIN_URL);
        httpMethod.setHeader("Accept", "text/html");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", userID));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
        httpMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpMethod);
        HttpEntity input = response.getEntity();
```

When the server receive these data it creates a session for that user and send back a success code. I want to know how to read the session ID for the respond header and how to set it to every next request header.

Comment: it'd just be a cookie, something along the lines of `sessionName=sessionID`, whatever the particular name/values are for your server-side environment, e.g. PHPSESSID=blahblahblah

Comment: when i iterate all the response header i get three header with the same name "Set-Cookie" with value like that
01-30 23:14:31.738: E/value(5685): CAKEPHP=b8b105b7fc845a340ceaff04f6ae4ef5; expires=Tue, 31-Jan-2012 01:14:29 GMT; path=/
how can i make use of that

Answer (score 1):

I think that this will get you to the point.
You will have to grab the cookies and include them in your HTTP request.

Get the cookies from the Login request:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        // Create a local instance of cookie store
        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

        // Create local HTTP context
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.yourpage/");

        System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());

        // Pass local context as a parameter
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
        }
        List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Local cookie: " + cookies.get(i));
        }

        // Consume response content
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

    } finally {
        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

Then pass them as a local contect:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yourpage/");

// Pass local context as a parameter     
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, localContext);
```

Comment: sorry but i didn't get what you mean.where can i get the sessionId value?and where can i use it again in any next request?

Comment: I added my answer, this should get you started.

Comment: thank you it works now.i think the problem was with the authentication  mechanism on the server